# Notification when a special AppleID/device connects to internet?

Tags: iphone, icloud, wifi, apple-id

I like to know when my wife's iPhone is connected to wifi (Internet). It's for good! I'm not spying or anything! She is in a place where she doesn't have celular data connection. I like to know when her iPhone is connected to Internet via wifi so that we can communicate. Is there an app/website/service for this? I'm sure it's possible somehow using AppleID. I can think of two non-optimal ways now.

1. I can login to icloud.com using her AppleID user/pass and use Find My iPhone service to see if the phone is connected.
2. I can send a message via iMessage and check whether the message is delivered or not.

Both of these are **polling** methods. I'm looking for an **interrupt** based solution. Computer Engineers know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ask her to send you a message via iMessage when she has wifi connection.

Comment: OK, interrupt based: she could write an email with subject "I'm online!" and send it to you without WiFi coverage. The message will remain in Mail's Outbox folder as it can't be delivered. As soon as her iPhone joins a WiFi network the message will be sent and you'll know that you can chat/facetime/skype with her. For best results add her email address to your VIP list (http://email.about.com/od/iphonemailtips/qt/How-To-Get-Vip-Email-Alerts-In-Ios-Mail.htm) and set an alert tone (http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/02/set-a-unique-alert-tone-for-new-mail-messages-from-vip-list-in-ios/).

Comment: I'd like to have an app do this for me. Maybe I need to write it myself. Just an app that sends a super small message periodically to me.

Comment: @jaume I already have her in my VIP list cause she is VIP :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, iOS devices only connect to Apple's push notification servers when they connect to the network, so you would need to interact with that system as a paid developer or consumer of a MDM solution that allows you to send notifications and retrieve status when messages are sent and received to that phone.

It's not a hard engineering problem, but you need to get software installed on her device by jailbreaking or by means that Apple approves. An app that registers for a local notification and attempts to send a http request to your web server is all you'd need to track each poll interval that she has an internet connection.

Realistically, you will probably end up asking here to reply to a message you send and trusting that iMessage will send a "delivered" message to your phones promptly after her phone registers to the APNS servers and gets the messages that are queued for her device/account.